# Add moving watermark with CSS over html5 video?

Tags: html, css, video

So I currently have something that looks a bit like this:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video_1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

And I want to get a watermark text to hover over over the video, something like this:

```
<p class="watermark-vid">Student 141</P>
```

Note, that while on web users would easily be able to hide the watermark, I'm creating an ElectronJs application so they won't have access to developer tools.

Comment: https://codepen.io/cincopa/pen/ZqaKqe
Does this help?

Comment: I want to use html5 or at least an open source package, instead of proprietary software, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the answer given by @Maxim Jin to add the "moving" aspect of a moving watermark. I also found a way to fix the fullscreen issue, I basically used the browser's fullscreen API to make the component itself go fullscreen.

Edit: Codepen of the answer: https://codepen.io/mahmoudthepeltist/pen/abNjvqR

```
<div id="vid-cont" class="video-container">
    <video class="video" controls>
        <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4' id='mp4'>
    </video>

    <p class="watermark">Student 141</P>
    <button class="fullscreen-button" onclick="activateFullscreen()">toggle fullscreen</button>
</div>
```

I also used the shadow DOM to hide the fullscreen button and replaced it with my own button that toggles fullscreen.

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
}

.video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
{
    display: none !important;
}

.fullscreen-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%; left: 90%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%; top: 3%;
    color: white;
    animation: 15s moving-watermark infinite;
}

@keyframes moving-watermark {
    0%   {left: 3%; top: 3%;}
    25% {left: 93%; top: 3%;}
    50% {left: 93%; top: 93%;}
    75% {left: 3%; top: 93%;}
    100% {left: 3%; top: 3%;}
}
```

The toggle is done in javascript:

```
function activateFullscreen() {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        document.getElementById('vid-cont').requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="video-container">
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
  <source src="video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video_1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<p class="watermark-vid">Student 141</P>
</div>

.video-container {
position: relative;
}

.video-container .watermark-vid {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: This is good, but it has one main problem. The watermark disappeared when the video goes into full screen mode.

Comment: I think that we should add the z-index. .watermark-vid { z-index: 9999999; }

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work unfortunately, due to the fact that fullscreen basically hides all the elements except the fullscreen one.

Comment: Could you show me the codepen or something ? let me check it